# postgresql query to add new key value pairs to existing json

Tags: json, postgresql

I need to add new key value pairs in the json

Json:

```
{
        "db": "postgres",
        "name": "test",
        "age" : 35
                          -->// need to insert here new key value pairs
}
```

after inserted the new key value pairs
Json

```
{
        "db": "postgres",
        "name": "test,
        "age" : 35,
        "newValue" : {
               "test" : {}
         }
}
```

Looking for the similar query

```
UPDATE table_name set column_name = column_name || '{"newValue": {
               "test" : {}
         }}' :: jsonb where id = "myId"
```

I tried with the above query by inserting the key value pairs out side the json

Comment: What was wrong with the query that you tried?

Comment: The new key value pairs are inserting outside the json eg:- {"old": "value"}"new":"value" it is inserting in this manner, but I need to insert {"old":"value","new":"value"} in this manner

Comment: @MatBailie, The new key value pairs are inserting outside the json eg:- {"old": "value"}{"new":"value"} it is inserting in this manner, but I need to insert {"old":"value","new":"value"} in this manner

Comment: Seems to do exactly what you asked : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a451057041267be7918b57f045148d25

Comment: What is the type of `column_name`?  If it is text, then add a cast like so:  `set column_name = column_name::jsonb || . . . `